# Application using Excel and C# to read search and write a workbook

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Need to create a application in C# with Win Forms the applications need to do the following:

1.Open a excel workbook in the background the user should not see this step
2. Then save the data in some way to the application so it can be accessed later
3. Receive a 8 digit identification code from a text box and search for a entry in the excel workbook containing the same digit
4.When the relevant entry is found the application should write the current time and date to a cell Sign-In and at the specific date the entry is done.
5. The application should then save the workbook automatically and 
6.Then close the application.

Can anyone help me please the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [closedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), it sits on top of Excel Interop and makes things easier.
But with out any examples of what you have tried it is really hard to tell you how to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have old-excel support (.xls), you can use `Wrapper.OpenXml` which available as [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Wrapper.OpenXml).